# Text Field with hidden content when read, but visible when writing

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I need a text field with the following behavior:

When the field is rendered, the current contents are hidden with password style (******), but if the user tries to edit it, the field gets cleared and they see on clear text what they are typing (so the behaviour is not entirely equivalent to PasswordTextField).

Any idea on how to achieve this behavior?
Thank you!

Comment: You could take a look at `AjaxEditableLabel` from WicketExtensions which is a label that turns into an editable input when you click on it. You could style the label to look like an input and change/override the code so that it only displays **** and then also override the onEdit method to clear the input that is in the background every time it switched to edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use some JavaScript to turn the field readable when focus event is fired. Here you can find a simple script that does the magic:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_password.asp

UPDATE:

In order to get the required behavior try the following code in the page above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput" onfocus="myFunction()"><br><br>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
  x.value = "";
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! There is a problem with this approach, the idea is that the user cannot see the original value, they should only be able to change it. But if the original value arrives to the client, a savvy (or malitious) user could easily unmask the value of the field.

Comment: I see. Then you could slightly change the code in the example to use the focus event of the PasswordTextField in order to clean it and make it readable. I've updated my original comment.